# Security risk among shared wifi users

Tags: tls, wifi, tor

I understand that the shared users on a wifi can see each other's HTTP traffic using proper tools. Is it possible for shared users to read HTTPS traffic or encrypted traffic like TOR ?

Comment: it is not answered sufficiently there.

Comment: SPRBRN's answer covers your question.

Comment: A pointed out in comment below , the referenced duplicate does not answer for the case of https / tor traffic

Answer (score 1):

The referenced duplicate does not explicitly address encrypted traffic by HTTPS and TOR. That httpS encrypted traffic can be accessed and whether or not users that share a WiFi network use WiFi encryption. That part is explained in the referenced 'duplicate'.

Decrypting the accessed httpS or TOR traffic is another topic. It may be interesting to know that banks in Netherlands recently advised against using httpS over public (encrypted or not) WiFi because of MitM /SSL stripping attacks. see https://www.security.nl/posting/389223/Banken%3A+niet+internetbankieren+via+open+wifi-netwerk  (sorry in Netherlands)

Comment: question says "can read", which means able to know the actual content. my worry is why somebody who can capture the entire traffic cannot capture the decryption key in case of https/tor and know the actual traffic.

Comment: Agree, should have said 'can access' and changed that. The warning of our banks though, definitely concerns 'can read'